# Get a list of all checkboxes in an array with 1 or 0 depending on checked or unchecked in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I want to have an `array` in `jquery` to hold values like `[0,1,1,0]` where 1 means the particular checkbox is checked otherwise if 0 then unchecked.

```js
function findout() {

var selected = [];
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).is('checked'));
});

$('span').text('checkbox values are: ' + selected.join(','));

}

findout();

$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', findout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
</div>
<span></span>
```

The checkbox value does not change it simply stays false and also i want value as 0,1 and not true,false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of little issues with your code. Just look at one problem at a time and use a ton of console.log calls to debug. Hope this working snippet helps!

```js
function findout() {

  var selected = [];
  $('input').each(function() {
    selected.push( $(this).prop('checked') ? 1 : 0 );
  });

  $('span').text('checkbox values are: ' + selected.join(','));

}

findout();

$('input').on('click', findout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
</div>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer use `$('input').each...` which will include all types of inputs in results (not only checkboxes), it could produce some 0(false) regarding textbox or button inputs which is not probably what you want!

Its better to use `$("[type=checkbox]")` to get all checkboxes:

according to [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/):

> Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   [type="checkbox"] instead.

```js
function findout() {

var selected = [];
$("[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).prop("checked")? 1 : 0 );
});

$('span').text('Checkbox values are: ' + selected.join(','));

}

findout();

$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', findout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: I think no need to use `each` at all.

Answer (score 0):

While you got your solution by @JasonB answer, But another solution *(maybe for future)* about using `$.map`.

```js
$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', findout);

function findout() {

  var selected = [];

  $(':checkbox').on('change', function() {

    var selected = $.map($(':checkbox'), function(el, idx) {
      if ($(el).is(':checked')) {
        return 1
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    });

    $('span').text('checkbox values are: ' + selected.join(','));

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" />
</div>
<span></span>
```